# Scraping string from HTML with python3-beautifulsoup3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get string from a table row using beautifulsoup.
String I want to get are 'SANDAL' and 'SHORTS', from second and third rows.
I know this can be solved with regular expression or with string functions but I want to learn beautifulsoup and do as much as possible with beautifulsoup.

Clipped python code

```
    soup=beautifulsoup(page,'html.parser')
    table=soup.find('table')
    row=table.find_next('tr')
    row=row.find_next('tr')
```

HTML

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="body">
    <div class="data">
    
    <table id="products">
    
    <tr><td>PRODUCT<td class="ole1">ID<td class="c1">TYPE<td class="ole1">WHEN<td class="ole4">ID<td class="ole4">ID</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SANDAL<td class="ole1">77313<td class="ole1">wear<td class="ole1">new<td class="ole4">id<td class="ole4">878717</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SHORTS<td class="ole1">77314<td class="ole1">wear<td class="ole1">new<td class="ole4">id<td class="ole4">878718</td></tr>
    
    </table>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text from first column of the table (sans header), you can use this script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="body">
    <div class="data">

    <table id="products">

    <tr><td>PRODUCT<td class="ole1">ID<td class="c1">TYPE<td class="ole1">WHEN<td class="ole4">ID<td class="ole4">ID</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SANDAL<td class="ole1">77313<td class="ole1">wear<td class="ole1">new<td class="ole4">id<td class="ole4">878717</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SHORTS<td class="ole1">77314<td class="ole1">wear<td class="ole1">new<td class="ole4">id<td class="ole4">878718</td></tr>

    </table>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')  # <-- lxml is important here (to parse the HTML code correctly)

for tr in soup.find('table', id='products').find_all('tr')[1:]:  # <-- [1:] because we want to skip the header
    print(tr.td.text)                                            # <-- print contents of first <td> tag
```

Prints:

```
SANDAL
SHORTS
```